# Html float: left div same sizes not working

Tags: html, css

I have 2 div with `float: left;` attributes. My problem that I've tried everything but doesn't look the same size:

[image: proof]

Here is my first `<div>` css:

```
#container-div {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: table;
}
.first-column-container-div {
    width: 173px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: -500em;
    padding-bottom: 500em;
    display: table-cell;
}
.first-column-names-container-div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 173px;
}
.first-column-names-h1 {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90.0deg); /* FF3.5+ */
    -o-transform: rotate(-90.0deg); /* Opera 10.5 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90.0deg); /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083); /* IE6,IE7 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083)"; /* IE8 */
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

and the second `<div>`:

```
.second-column-container-div {
    width: 173px;
    float: left;
    display: table-cell;
}
.second-column-values-container-div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-left: none;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MysticUnicorn

The best way to fix this is Flex box - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

**Git** https://gist.github.com/bharadhwaj-g/42d53535d2311b00e8a215f2b4c518f6

Answer (score 2):

you just need to give second box's height to first box. we can give this height using js only. please follow below code:

first take second box's height,

```
var box2_height = $('.second-column-container-div').height();
```

and then give it to first box's height,

```
$('.first-column-container-div').height(box2_height);
```

Comment: @mystic unicorn if it worked for you then please accept it. Thank You.